# Boto3 Deploy to Elastic-beanstalk not reading Config files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, boto3

I am using boto3 to deploy my environment to elastic beanstalk using the [create_environment](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/elasticbeanstalk.html#ElasticBeanstalk.Client.create_application) function.  I have my configuration files in the .elasticbeanstalk folder but the deploy doesn't seem to be using them.  When I deploy the same environment using the eb client it works exactly as wanted. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.

boto3 uses the aws api, which does not read the configuration files but rather reads a json configuration option (called option_settings). These allow you to configure all of your post-ec2-deploy settings (Everything you can change from the elastic beanstalk configuration page).

However, if you want to adjust configuration for what your ec2 instance has installed before your application runs (things like package installs, file creation, etc.) then you will have to create an aws image of a ec2 instance you like, and then reference that image id from the option_settings.

obviously the eb client does all of the above for you by reading the configuration files.