# Can boto3 be used for deployment of an ElasticBeanstack application?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I've successfully been able to create and deploy ElasticBeanstalk environments using the `eb cli` tool, however now I'm trying to get my head around boto3 and deploying code.

But I can't for the life of me figure out how to actually deploy an app (or whatever the package containing the `.ebextensions` folder is called) using boto3.

Using `eb cli`, running `eb deploy` packages up that directory and uploads it all to AWS, with any changes to the `.ebextensions` to deploy the app.

However the [docs for elasticbeanstalk for boto3](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/elasticbeanstalk.html) include:

- `create_application()` - just makes the app specification, no uploading
- `create_application_version()` - pulls a link to an app version, but I can't make one or upload one
- `create_environment()` - makes the broader environment, still no good.

How do I actually deploy an app using `boto`, or am I stuck with `eb cli`?

Comment: The [same](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37626142/4296747) was asked pretty recently with no answer - I think you're left with using CLI tools

Comment: I just saw this, not sure it will fix in your scenario. 

http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/elasticbeanstalk.html#ElasticBeanstalk.Client.update_application

Comment: @mootmoot that only covers changing details, not uploading the package.

Comment: @FrédéricHenri lame, thanks.

Comment: well, they (all aws APIs including ruby, java...) all mimic the aws CLI methods - not clear to me why aws made a different `eb` CLI tooling not part of aws CLI